# I Would like to open at a time one show / hide plus minus table

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#t1").hide(); // hide table by default
        $("#close").hide(); //hide the minus button as well if you only want one button to display at a time

  $('#sp1').on('click', function() { //when plus button is clicked
    $("#t1").show(); 
    $("#sp1").hide(); //you need to hide the plus button now
    $("#close").show(); //and then display the minus button
  });
  $('#close').on('click', function() { 
    $("#t1").hide(); //hide table
    $("#close").hide(); //hide minus btn
    $("#sp1").show(); //show plus button
  });
});
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#t2").hide(); // hide table by default
  $('#sp2').on('click', function() {
       toggleButtons(true);
    $("#t2").show();
  });
  $('#close2').on('click', function() {
       toggleButtons(false)
    $("#t2").hide();
  });
      function toggleButtons(show) {
      if (show) {
        $("#sp2").hide();
        $("#close2").show();
      } else {
        $("#sp2").show();
        $("#close2").hide();
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12 col-12 table-responsive">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding: 10px !important;" align="center">
      <div class="form-group">Main heading</div>
    </div>
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead class="lbbg3">
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 800px;">Sub heading 1</td>
          <td>Sub heading 2</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th style="background: #eef7fc; text-align: left;" colspan="2">
            <button class="table-plus-btn table1" id="sp1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button><button class="table-minus-btn" id="close"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> Child Heading
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div class="table1shw">
              <table class="table1 table-hover" id="t1">
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 1
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <a href="#doc">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadio50" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy edu docbtn" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio50" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()"></label>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 2
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <input type="radio" id="customRadio51" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy" />
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio51" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
           <tr>
          <th style="background: #eef7fc; text-align: left;" colspan="2">
            <button class="table-plus-btn table1" id="sp2"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button><button class="table-minus-btn" id="close2"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button> Child Heading2
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div class="table1shw">
              <table class="table1 table-hover" id="t2">
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 3
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <a href="#doc">
                        <input type="radio" id="customRadio50" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy edu docbtn" />
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio50" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()"></label>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
                    Row 4
                  </td>
                  <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
                      <input type="radio" id="customRadio51" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy" />
                      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio51" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi, i am not able to solve how to display one table once i click on the plus button. Right now i can open it both table. I need to see one at a time if i click one table other one need to go off. All the table will show properly. This one i had done in accordion but here i am not lucky. so please help

Comment: Do you mean you would like only one table to ever be visible at a time?

Comment: yes i need at time to display one table not both right now i can see both table.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using bootstrap, you should really consider how you can make your code more re-useable (and a little bit more readable, though for the most part you've done well with). I rewrote some of your code only to demonstrate the concept (hide all elements before displaying the one clicked)... I was too lazy to try and parse through yours to sort it all out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".allcontent").hide(); // hide table by default
        $(".hide").hide(); //hide the minus button as well if you only want one button to display at a time
        
        $('.show').on('click', function() {
          $('.allcontent').hide();
          $('.show').show();
          $('.hide').hide();
          $(this).parent().find('.show').hide();
          $(this).parent().find('.hide').show();
          $(this).parent().parent().find('.allcontent').show();
        });

        $('.hide').on('click', function() {
          $(this).parent().find('.show').show();
          $(this).parent().find('.hide').hide();
          $(this).parent().parent().find('.allcontent').hide();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-container">

  <div class="1st">
  
    <div class="2nd">
      <button class="show">
        +
      </button>
      <button class="hide">
        -
      </button>
    </div>

    <table class="table1 table-hover allcontent">
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
         Row 1
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
            <a href="#doc">
             <input type="radio" id="customRadio50" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy edu docbtn" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio50" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()">
            </label>
           </a>
         </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
         Row 2
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio51" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio51" style="cursor: pointer;">
            </label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="1st">
  
    <div class="2nd">
      <button class="show">
        +
      </button>
      <button class="hide">
        -
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <table class="table1 table-hover allcontent">
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
          Row 3
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
            <a href="#doc">
              <input type="radio" id="customRadio50" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy edu docbtn" />
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio50" style="cursor: pointer;" onchange="valueChanged()"></label>
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left; width: 800px;">
          Row 4
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-table">
            <input type="radio" id="customRadio51" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input fcy" />
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio51" style="cursor: pointer;"></label>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    
  </div>
  
</div>
```

EDIT:

There are maybe some ways to make the algorithm more efficient. For instance, as it stands the code works as follows:

1. a button is clicked.
2. get all the collapsable elements.
3. hide all elements.
4. show the element clicked.

A simple change to the algorithm would be to add an 'active' class. Which would mean the algorithm wouldn't have to traverse all of the items. Which effectively would look like:

1. a button is clicked.
2. get the element that was active, remove the 'active' class, and hide it.
3. add the 'active' class to the new element and show it.

Comment: @user3181077 if this answer is correct, would you please mark it as so?